# How do i use QComboBox.setPlaceholderText?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

In Qt **5.15** the `placeholderText` property was introduced - [link to documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#placeholderText-prop)

However **using `setPlaceholderText` doesn't do anything for me**. When running the code below i don't get any text in the `QComboBox` (unless of course i select one of the three items)

[image: combo-box]

Is this a bug or am i missing something? How can i make this work?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central_w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_w)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_w.setLayout(vbox)

        self.combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_box.addItems(["one", "two", "three"])
        self.combo_box.setPlaceholderText("Some placeholder text here")
        self.combo_box.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo_box)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I have found no way of showing the placeholder text. I've tried having no items at all in the combo box but even this doesn't show the placeholder text

---

These are the versions i am running:

- Qt: 5.15.2
- PyQt (Python module) version: 5.15.2 (this happens to be the same as the Qt version but can sometimes differ slightly)
- Python: "3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) \n[GCC 9.3.0]"
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (with Xfce)

---

PS: If you want to achieve a similar effect (that is: having a text on a clickable area which shows a drop-down with different options after being clicked) you can use a `QPushButton` with the `setMenu` function. Documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#setMenu

Comment: What's the output of `print(app.style().objectName()`? If it's not "fusion", try `app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`

Comment: @musicamante I got `app.style().objectName()='fusion'`. Btw i don't know if this matters but i'm running Xfce (i'll update this in the question)

Comment: Mmh. Can you try with the other available styles? You can see the full list with the static `QStyleFactory.keys()`. Also, can you try to change the palette, by explicitly setting the `placeholderText` role (ensuring that it has enough contrast and has no alpha)?

Comment: Try `PySide2` instead of `PyQt5`. I just tested it on Windows and it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reviewing the modifications of the Qt source code, it is observed that to add the functionality of the placeHolderText in Qt 5.15.0, the currentText() was modified:

```cpp
// https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox.cpp?h=5.15.0#n2344
QString QComboBox::currentText() const
{
    Q_D(const QComboBox);
    if (d->lineEdit)
        return d->lineEdit->text();
    else if (d->currentIndex.isValid())
        return d->itemText(d->currentIndex);
    else
        return d->placeholderText;
}
```

But that generates an undesirable effect that was reported in [QTBUG-86580](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86580) so that functionality was removed in Qt 5.15.2:

```cpp
QString QComboBox::currentText() const
{
    Q_D(const QComboBox);
    if (d->lineEdit)
        return d->lineEdit->text();
    if (d->currentIndex.isValid())
        return d->itemText(d->currentIndex);
    return {};
}
```

Forgetting to correct the side effect which is that the placeHolder is no longer visible. I have already reported the bug: [QTBUG-90522](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90522).

Considering the above, there are the following alternatives:

- Use PyQt5/PySide2 5.15.0 or 5.15.1.
- Override the paintEvent method to set the placeHolderText as currentText:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# or
# from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    # https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox.cpp?h=5.15.2#n3173
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Text))

        # draw the combobox frame, focusrect and selected etc.
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt)

        if self.currentIndex() < 0:
            opt.palette.setBrush(
                QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText,
                opt.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText).color().lighter(),
            )
            if self.placeholderText():
                opt.currentText = self.placeholderText()

        # draw the icon and text
        painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.combo_box = ComboBox()
        self.combo_box.addItems(["one", "two", "three"])
        self.combo_box.setPlaceholderText("Some placeholder text here")
        self.combo_box.setCurrentIndex(-1)

        central_w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_w)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_w)
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo_box)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: At me it works except of the color. The color looks the same as the other dropdown items.